# add Photos app to "Open in" menu- IOS?

Tags: ios, uidocumentinteraction

I'm creating an "Open in" menu in my app with `UIDocumentInteractionController`.
I want to add native Photos app to this menu but I don't know how to do that?
Can anyone point me a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't send to the camera roll through `UIDocumentInteractionController`. You have to do that one directly [using](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html):

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImage, completeTarget, completeSelector);
```

So you'll need to have an independent menu/icon item for it.